# How to change the Auto_Incriment value in MySQL db with PHP or SQL queries?

Tags: php, mysql

How to change the Auto_Incriment value in MySQL db with PHP or SQL queries ?

Hi all , I am having a problem when am saving my php created form in MySQL db , as I had given Auto_Incriment to an ID in my database & its working great but problem exist when I delete a ROW let's say having ID = 3 & 4 and after when I again store value from my PHP form into my DB then it gives ID=5 instead of giving 3 !!

below is the Image [image]

So is their any Query to correct it or any PHP coding so that I can get ID of last row from db and can increment it and then again store it in DB ??

Comment: this question has been asked a lot. It is best to leave the gaps. We often joke about it being an OCD thing otherwise. There are many reasons why you just want to leave it alone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not be what you want to hear, but as I mentioned in comments under question, there are reasons why you would want to leave it alone and have gaps.

One of the main reasons is unnecessary re-ordering (shrinking up numbers), all of which is unnecessary.

Another reason is the situation where you truly have child rows depending on id's that you have not established Foreign Key (FK) constraints with, but the id's match.

Trying to be clever and reshuffling numbers is asking for trouble. Your data integrity and ultimately sound FK constraints and non-orphaning are much more important than solving this fixation.

What is an orphan? An orphan is a child without a parent. If a child table row depends on a another (parent) table row with an `id`, and you leave the child without a parent, it becomes an orphan.

Perhaps as worse or more so is having the child row point to the wrong parent by doing that which you propose.

Mysql Manual Page on [Foreign Key Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).